# Trouble with plotting time series data

Tags: time-series, visualization

I am doing something wrong with X in these time series plots, but what?

This code using plotly yields the following ridiculous time series line plot:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['Weekly_Sales'])])
plt.savefig('plot2.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
fig.show()
```

[image: 1st Time Series plot]

Here is the basic data:

To show the error on my part (whatever it is) is ongoing, here is a second time series plot:

```
# Spec the chart size
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
x = df.index

#Plot the lines
plt.plot(x, weekly_roll)
plt.plot(x, monthly_roll) 
plt.plot(x, quarterly_roll) 
plt.plot(x, yearly_roll)

# Spec the x and y labels, chart title, and axis ticks
plt.yticks(fontsize=18)
plt.xticks(fontsize=18)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Revenue',
       title='Rolling Averages - Weekly Sales');
plt.savefig('plot4.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show();
```

Here is the resulting image:
[image: 2nd Time Series Plot]

While both plots have a certain modern flair, it's not what I am going for in a time series plot. Help?

Here is the basic data from the head() of the df:

```
Date    Store Dept Weekly_Sales IsHoliday           
2010-02-05  1   1   24924.50    False
2010-02-12  1   1   46039.49    True
2010-02-19  1   1   41595.55    False
2010-02-26  1   1   19403.54    False
2010-03-05  1   1   21827.90    False
```

Comment: Can you show some of the data you are using for your plots?

Comment: Shouldn't you be grouping by Store and Dept before you plot.  Seems that you are plotting one long series that spans all of the Stores and Depts.

Comment: Can you also explain what do you aim to plot ? a time serie for each store ? each dept ?

Comment: The departments are a subset of the store. There are two years of 'weekly_sales' reports for the store. My first task is to create a time-series plot of the 'weekly_sales' reports for the store.